# change template layout per component

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7, joomla-template

I have 1 template that has two columns.left with 250px width and right with 700px width.i want when component Banners called,Joomla only show one column with 950px width.how to this work?thanks.
I work with joomla1.7

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution for you.
Lets call your positions left, main and banner. Here's what you need to do (or how I would do it).

First, to keep your template clean, create new file vars.php in your template's root folder.
This file contains:

```
$mainWidth = 950;
if ($this->countModules( 'left' )):
$mainWidth = $mainWidth - 250;
endif;
```

Include file vars.php in your template's index.php file:

```
 <?php require_once('vars.php'); ?>
```

Change the main container div to:
    px">

Change the left container input:

```
<?php if ($this->countModules( 'left' )) : ?>
<div id="left"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="left" /></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now just simply turn off all modules in the left position, for banners component. :)